# Use Range Find Method in a specific column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been tinkering with this for a while now, I have the below code working but it searches more than I would like it to. I would like it to just search column C and not the entire sheet. I have tried changing out the `Cells.Find` to `Range("C1:C10000").Find` but it returns no matches.

Really stumped on this one.

```
Dim r As Range

Set r = Sheets("State Agent List").Range("C1:C10000").Find(What:=ComboBox22.Value, _
            After:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    r.Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
Else
    MsgBox "Location not listed."
End If
```

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work (currently not on a PC that has Excel installed). You could always brute force the logic by checking like `If Not r.Column = 3 Then Set r = Nothing`

Comment: perhaps ComboBox22.Value is not present in that range?  Perhaps there are some non-printing characters that you are not accounting for?  Your code seems to work OK here, with a valid parameter for  `What:=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `ActiveCell` which if happens to be not within `C1:C10000` will return nothing. Try this:

```
Dim searchRng As Range: Set searchRng = Sheets("State Agent List").Range("C1:C10000")
Dim r As Range
Set r = searchRng.Find(What:=ComboBox22.Value, After:=searchRng(searchRng.Count))
```

The argument `searchRng(searchRng.Count)` pertains to the last cell of the Range you're working on. It works but it can be written explicitly this way:

```
searchRng.Cells(searchRng.Cells.Count)
```

Why do we need to set the `After` argument to the last cell?
Main reason is for the search to begin from the very first cell. HTH

Comment: Thank you heaps, this solved my issue and gave me some ideas on how to improve my workbook which I just implemented without an issue as well. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can also just leave out the `After` argument, in which case -  " If you do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I would like to add that the After argument you've added, , After:=searchRng(searchRng.Cells.Count), will cause a conflict with the argument, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, which starts searching from the bottom, not the top.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this

- ensure you start searching from C1 in case there are multiple matches (given you are setting a scrollwindow)
- `xlFormulas` finds cells in hidden rows, `xlValues` skips them
- no need for the `Select`

  ```
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Set rng1 = Sheets("State Agent List").Range("C1:C10000").Find(CStr(ComboBox22.Value), [c10000], xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlNext)

  If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
      ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = rng1.Row
  Else
      MsgBox "Location not listed."
  End If
  ```