# Range.Find in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to perform a "find" in a Excel sheet with this instruction:

```
Set Found = Columns(2).Find(What:=value_to_find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

but I get the error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

If I use Range("A1:H1") instead of Columns(2) I don't get any errors, but I think they are both type Range.

My aim is use a Range variable, at the start of the script I valorize it according to the user's choice.

Comment: Suppose you wrap your Columns call in Range, i.e., `Range(Columns(2)).Find(...)`?  I don't have Excel handy to try this.

Comment: Is `ActiveCell` definitely within `Columns(2)`? If not, there will be an error - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Range Find Method in a specific column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333965/use-range-find-method-in-a-specific-column)

Comment: What is the variable type for `Found`?

Comment: The variable Found (in your code) must be of type variant. So, if you explicitly set Dim Found as variant then your code should work.

Comment: I don't know why but thanks the Ralph's answer, my script is working now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVED] 
Many Thanks everyone, I resolved my question with the Ralph's support.

> The variable Found (in your code) must be of type variant. So, if you explicitly set Dim Found as variant then your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as @barrowc commented.

This works although not sure of exact requirements:

```
Sub xxx()

Dim value_to_find As String
value_to_find = "fooBar"

Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Find( _
    What:=value_to_find, _
    After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False)

MsgBox r.Address

End Sub
```

[image]