# Macros for VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have two excel workbooks. Now What I want to is take the value of the column selected and search that in another workbook and focus that particular row. How can I do this using VBA?

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you select. VBScript and VBA are not the same thing. Also [macros] doesn't refer to VBA macro. Having said that, what have you tried so far? There are a lot of questions about finding values in a range using VBA. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28664035/4934172), for example.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're looking in both first sheets:

```
  Sub find_in_other_wb()
      On Error goto found_nothing
      Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Workbooks("put book name here").Sheets(1)

      msgbox "Found in row " & ws2.Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Find(ActiveCell.Value).Row
    exit sub
found_nothing:
    msgbox "Couldn't find that"
End Sub
```

will give out the row , after selecting the cell containing the value you're looking for. This Sub may be efficient if you use a shortcut for it.