# For each range including a variable-problem

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in a small part of my code : I want it to select the cells starting from `c` which is a cell meeting a condition that I have defined earlier, to the end of the list. In this range, I want it to copy the first value that exceeds `resultat` (a value obtained before).

```
With Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A2:A5181")
 Set c = .Find(Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("A14").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
  If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = c.Address
    Do
 Range(Range(c), Range(c).End(xlDown)).Select
  If c Is Nothing Then
        GoTo DoneFinding
    End If
    Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
  End If
DoneFinding:
End With

Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim resultat As Double
Dim Cel As Range
Dim firstValue As Integer
Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

s1 = Worksheets("Feuil2").Range(c)
s2 = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(s1).End(xlDown)
Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(s1 & ":" & s2).Select


For Each Cel In Range(s1 & ":" & s2)
    If Cel.Value >= resultat Then
        firstValue = Cel.Value
        firstAddress = Cel.Address
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Worksheets("Feuil1").firstValue.Copy
Range("C14").Worksheet("Feuil2").PasteSpecial
```

I get an error for the 2 first lines of the code.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**This is my new code, because I realized something is missing.. The `SearchRange` does not start from row 2, but from the row where the value (a date) is equal to the last date of ws2.** I get an error for my `For each line`. It says Object required.

***Edit - New code, object error at rangyrange :***

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rangyrange As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws1Cell As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim Cel As Range
Dim firstValue As Double
Dim A15Value As Date
Dim firsty As Long
Dim newRange As Range
Dim lastRow2 As Long

Set ws1 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
Set ws2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2")


A15Value = CDate(ws2.Cells(15, 1).Value)

With ws1

 lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

  Set foundRange = ws1.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))
  Set searchRange = foundRange.Find(A15Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
  Set rangyrange = ws1.Range(.Cells(searchRange.Row, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))
  firsty = rangyrange.Rows(1).Row

  Set newRange = ws1.Range(.Cells(firsty, 2), .Cells(lastRow2, 2))

End With

 For Each ws1Cell In newRange
   If ws1Cell.Value >= resultat Then

     firstValue = ws1Cell.Value

   firstAddress = ws1Cell.Address
Exit For
   End If
Next


ws2.Cells(15, 3).Value = firstValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this different from your other question? I just posted a comment on your other one.

Comment: The `Set` statement for `ws1LastCell` wasn't copied correctly; you incorrectly broke the statement into two separate lines. Just put it all on 1 line if you don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: Also, I noticed that `Set searchRange = ws1.Range("A1:F1")` hasn't changed from when I posted it. Is that intentional?

Comment: `ws1.firstValue.Copy` doesn't do anything because `firstValue` is just a number that's not associated with the worksheet. You already have the value stored in a variable, so you can do `ws2.Range("C14").Value = firstValue` if what you're trying to do is put `firstValue` into the cell `C14` in `ws2`.

Comment: @jcrizk the `Set` statement for `ws1` is in one line, I don't know why it shows like that here. For the `searchRange` , I didn't really understand what it looks for ? I didn't change it because I thought it was just the range from columns A to F. I'm not sure.... And I still get he same error

Comment: If I understood well, I changed it to  `Set searchRange = ws1.Range("A1:A5182")` because that's where the value I'm looking for is. @jcrizk

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through rows A1:A14?

Comment: @jcrizk No I'm looking for a value in my column A of ws1, that is equal to the value A14 of ws2.

Comment: ok that makes a lot more sense

Comment: @jcrizk , do you have an idea for the error message I get, at the  `Set ws1LastCell` level ? I still get it, although I changed my code according to your comments

Comment: I updated my answer because you said -> (No I'm looking for a value in my column A of ws1, that is equal to the value A14 of ws2. ) it's under **New Edit:**

Comment: I had an error in my answer, but i corrected it.

Comment: @jcrizk it returns something, but it's not the value of the cell, nor the row number. It returns "35881". I have no idea what that is :p

Comment: @jcrizk I edited my post if you can please check.

Comment: @Narjems I changed a few things in **New Edits:**. `A14Value = CDbl(ws2.Cells(14, 1).Value)` to `A14Value = CDate(ws2.Cells(14, 1).Value)` // `If ws1Cell.Value >= A14Value Then` to `If CDate(ws1Cell.Value) >= A14Value Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim c As Range

Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(c), Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(c).End(xlDown))
```

You haven't set `c` to a range, so VBA doesn't understand what you're doing.

Also, I suggest defining a worksheet variable to increase the readability of your code like this:

```
Set ws = Excel.Application.Worksheets("Feuil1")
```

And your statement becomes much more legible:

```
ws.Range(ws.Range(c), ws.Range(c).End(xlDown))
```

This is not how you reference a range, also, I would suggest never using `.Select`.

```
Range(s1 & ":" & s2).Select
```

This is how you reference a range:

```
'this is my preferred method of referencing a range
Set someVariable = ws.Range(ws.Cells(row, column), ws.Cells(row, column))
```

Or...

```
'this is useful in some instances, but this basically selects a cell
Set someVariable = ws.Range("B2")
```

Or...

```
'this references the range A1 to B1
Set someVariable = ws.Range("A1:B1")
```

Also, as @BigBen pointed out, you cannot set a range like so:

```
Dim c As Range
s1 = Worksheets("Feuil2").Range(c)
```

The reasons being:

1. `c` hasn't been assigned.
2. You can't use a range as an input unless it's of the form `ws.Range(ws.Cells(row, column), ws.Cells(row, column))`

Per your update that includes the assignment for `c`:

> I get an error for the 2 first lines of the code.

This is because you're assigning `c` before you're declaring `c`.

You should have all of your `Dim` statements preceding your actual code (unless you know what you're doing) like so:

```
Public Sub MySub()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim resultat As Double
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim firstValue As Integer
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

    `the rest of your code
End Sub
```

I would change your `Do` loop to the following:

```
With Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A2:A5181")
    Set c = .Find(Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("A14").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = c.Address
        Do While c.Address <> firstAddress
            'I'm unsure of the goal here, so I'm ignoring it
            Range(Range(c), Range(c).End(xlDown)).Select
            If c Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End With
```

Mainly because I hate GoTo statements and because the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement) for `Do` loops states to use either `Do While` or `Do Until` instead of `Loop While` or `Loop Until`

`s1` and `s2` are strings, so you can't do this:

```
s1 = Worksheets("Feuil2").Range(c)
s2 = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(s1).End(xlDown)
```

I'm assuming you want to get the column and row of `c` and iterate through that, but the problem is that you're working in 2 `different` worksheets, which you can't do. I'll assume it's an error and that you want to work on the "Fueil2" worksheet, so here goes:

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim startCell As Range
Dim endCell As Range
Dim foundRange As Range

Set ws2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fueil2")
With ws2
    Set startCell = .Cells(c.Row, c.Column)
    Set endCell = .Cells(c.End(xlUp).Row, c.Column)
    Set foundRange = .Range(.Cells(c.Row, c.Column), .Cells(c.End(xlUp).Row, c.Column))

    For Each Cel In foundRange
        'yada yada yada
End With
```

**Post-lunch Edit:**

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664035/range-find-in-vba-excel) is a bit misleading because I tested this snippet and it works:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim foundRange As Range
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim workRange As Range
    Dim foundColumn As Range
    Dim ws1LastCell As Range
    Dim ws1Range As Range
    Dim iWantThis As Range

    Set ws1 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set searchRange = ws1.Range("A1:F1")
    Set foundRange = searchRange.Find(ws2.Range("C1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

    With foundRange
        'last cell in the ws1 column that's the same column as foundRange
        Set ws1LastCell = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(.Row, .Column), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, .Column)).End(xlDown)
        'the range you want
        Set iWantThis = ws1.Range(foundRange, ws1LastCell)
        'check to see if it got what i wanted on ws1
        iWantThis.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

**New Edit:**

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim c14Value As Double
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws1Cell As Range

    Set ws1 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'gets the date
    A14Value = CDate(ws2.Cells(14, 1).Value)

    With ws1
        'gets the last row's number in column A on worksheet 1
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'selects from A2 to the last row with data in it. this works only if
        'there aren't any empty rows between your data, and that's what i'm assuming.
        Set searchRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))
    End With

    For Each ws1Cell In searchRange
        If CDate(ws1Cell.Value) >= A14Value Then
            'i didnt make a variable for firstValue
            firstValue = ws1Cell.Value
            'i didnt make a variable for firstAddress
            firstAddress = ws1Cell.Address
        Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'puts firstValue into cell C14 on ws2
    ws2.Cells(14, 3).Value = firstValue
End Sub
```

Until I see a definition for `resultat`, I'm assuming it's 100% correctly declared and assigned. hint: You should give us your declaration and assignment of `resultat` because I can't fully determine if how you defined `resultat` is an issue.

Comment: Thank you @jcrizk for your help, for your precious help. Your code works, I had to modify my data (my dates were as a European format). I'm sorry that my question was messy, I'll do better next time. :)